# Application always returning status code 200 when running on k8s Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Recently we've created a cluster on Kubernetes Engine (GCP) and we started to notice a strange behavior.

When a request is made to the application through the load balancer, its **always receiving status code 200**, even when the application returns an error code (ex: 401). Seems like some layer of the cluster is intercepting and replacing it.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

To be sure about the theory, I've made other tests using the **port-forward** feature of `kubectl`, making requests directly to the POD. And doing this way, I've got the response codes correctly.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Has anyone ever been through this situation before or have any idea how can we debug it better and discover what is causing this behavior?

**EDIT:**

After making more few tests, I've realized another interesting thing. When the requests are made by the browser (as a simple GET), it shows status code `200`.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But when I try the same GET requests using form the `curl` command, it shows the right code.

[image]

Comment: It seems to me Kube-proxy is the one who does converting of the request as well directing to the right pod. So I might suggest you to check IP-tables rules or check the header of the HTTP requests. From My experience, Http headers are hidden trouble creators.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi thanks for the comment. I've investigated it deeper, in order to find something strange with the headers, and saw an interesting thing. The browser shows the status code differently than the `curl` command. I've updated the question with more information.

Comment: have you eliminated browser caching as an issue by doing a hard refresh or incognito session?

Comment: Hey @navicore, yup. I think I've discovered the cause of the problem. We are using Traefik as load balancer. And there is a bug in the version `1.4.2` (current applied) that makes the header been mounted wrong in HTTP2 context. (https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/2351).

I will upgrade it to the `1.4.3` (solution patch) and see what happens. If it works, I will place a feedback here.